# Querying most recent batch data from SQL database from Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to automatically process data in python using a direct query to our SQL database.  This part is done, but the code specifies the runnumber each time and when a new batch starts, you have to re-input the newest runnumber into the code before you can proceed - a waste of time and on a recurring basis!

df = pd.read_sql(f"Select time, temp from datatable where machineid=84207 and runnumber=1616862158", conn)

I'd like to update this code with the most recent runnumber (the most recent runnumber will always be a maximum value in the database for each machine) without having to look up and type in the most recent runnumber.  There are many different machines that are all collecting data into the SQL database, hence having to specify each dataframe with each machineid.  Again, that part of the code is finished and I can replicate for all machines. However, I don't want to do this runnumber for each one, as it will dynamically change over time.

So I'm trying to find a way to either create a string that will define the max runnumber automatically such as this:

pp1 = pd.read_sql(f"Select Max(runnumber) from datatable where machineid=84207", conn)
print(pp1)

```
      max
```

0   1616862158

Is there a way I can substitute this value contained within "pp1" into a string in the query line below?  Or set the runnumber=max?  I'm not familiar enough with the syntax or options within the WHERE commands or python commands to set this up.  Can someone help?

df = pd.read_sql(f"Select time, temp from datatable where machineid=84207 and runnumber=1616862158", conn)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add some formatting to your code :) (indent with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a subquery in the where statement like this.

```
select time, temp from datatable where machineid=84207 and runnumber=(select max(runnumber) from datatable)
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much!